# Perform value alteration in model as default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I need to do some basic value calculations to a Rails model's data prior to the controller rendering as JSON. This is an API for a store.. Products have one price and belong to a store. In our price table we have a column called "amount" (decimal) which stores the cost of the product.

On the price model what I'm trying to do is perform a calculation on said amount as we need to add a price margin.

In my Products controller is then where the query is built, however, the amount is never calculated and rather the cost stored in the DB is outputted in the JSON. Price is included on the products query using includes. Currently, the rails logger throws an error saying "NoMethodError (undefined method `amount' for #)".

```
class API::ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
    @department = params[:department_id]
    @aisle = params[:aisle_id]
    if @department.present?
    @products = Product.includes(:department).includes(:aisle).where("products.store_id @> '{?}'", params[:id].to_i).includes(:price).where('prices.store_id = ?', params[:id]).references(:prices).limit(params[:max])
    end
  render json: @products
end
```

Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :department
    belongs_to :aisle
    has_one :price


    def as_json(options)
        super(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :image, :weight, :store_id],
            :include => {
            :price => {:only => [:amount, :store_id]},
            :department => {:only =>[:name, :id]},
            :aisle => {:only => [:name, :id]}
            }
        )
    end
end
```

Price Model where I'm trying to do the price calculation depending on the amount (decimal):

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :store


    case self.amount
    when proc {|n| n <= 1}
      return self.amount * 0.15
    when 115..135
      return self.amount * 0.15
    when 135..500
      return self.amount * 0.15
  end
end
```

Jbuilder/rabl are out of the question at this point as my project is nearly complete and it would take too long to try to go back and change/re implement everything.

Comment: `self.amount` meas, that you define a method `amount` on the class `Price`, not on the instances of the class.

Comment: Just curious. why isn't the amount calculation, a class method?

Comment: do you want to change the value of amount attribute? because there is a `write_attribute` method which allows you to do exactly that. `def amount=(amount) write_attribute(:amount, amount * 0.15) end`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I don't want to change it in the database (it should remain the same) but on the model I want the value to differ yes

Comment: so you just need the method, right? And method can have any name or exactly `amount`?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko well in the as_json method where I'm building the json format output, I'm referencing :amount so I suppose it would need to be called amount still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the same method name as a column in db and not to create endless loops you can reference `super`:

```
  def amount
    case super
    when 0..1
      (super + super * 0.15)
    when 115..135
      (super + super * 0.20)
    when 136..500
      (super + super * 0.25)
    else
      (super + super * 0.40)
    end
  end
```

Be aware, that with this method you won't have any changes for amount which is in range of `2..114`.
Also, you had ranges like 115..135 and next one as 135..500. It leaves breaches, since what to do with amount of 135? Which rule to apply? Be precise.

It is your turn to adjust tha case statement to your needs. Be careful

Comment: Okay, this is almost working. Instead of returning the amount PLUS an additonal 15% it's just returning what the value of 15% would be (for example ($0.20). Which I guess I just need to add the regular value to it at this point.

Comment: @JonGirard absolutely right, good point (it's still morning here in Poland). Now you have it

Comment: excellent thank you. Is there anyway to use when too like I was before for different price amounts and then perform the calculation. For example, if the amount is $2.00, add 20%?

Comment: sure, I can rewrite you case statement, it just seemed to always multiply by 0.15

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, I just did it for simplicity. In production I will have varying amounts. Would it just be def amount case super and then the proc?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately. An end is just missing maybe?

Comment: app/models/price.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected <=
  app/models/price.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
  app/models/price.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting keyword_end
  app/models/price.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
  app/models/price.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting keyword_end
  app/models/price.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
  app/controllers/api/products_controller.rb:14:in `index'

Comment: SyntaxError (/Users/jongirard/Rails/app/models/price.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected <=
     when <= 1
            ^
/Users/jongirard/Rails/app/models/price.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
     when 115..135
         ^
/Users/jongirard/Rails/app/models/price.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting end-of-input
     when 136..500
         ^):

Comment: may be it does not like the `<=`. edited it to be a range

Comment: This seemed to work like this: def amount
     case super
     when proc {|n| n <= 0325}
       return super + super * 0.15
  when 0326..0500
       return super + super * 0.20
  when 0501..10
       return super + super * 0.15
     else
       return super + super * 0.15
     end
   end

Answer (score 1):

Your Price class needs to have this method instead of the straightforward calculation:

```
def something_amount
  case self.amount
    when proc {|n| n <= 1}
      self.amount * 0.15
    when 115..135
      self.amount * 0.15
    when 135..500
      self.amount * 0.15
  end
end
```

and then call this method when you want the altered amount in your query

Comment: This would actually create an endless loop in the code